# How to transfer a file from remote windows OS to local Linux filesystem?

Tags: scp

I know scp is able to upload and download between Linux servers, and also upload from Windows to Linux server. But is downloading from Windows to Linux possible?

To clarify, the requirement is to run the CLI command on the Linux server to download a file from the remote windows server

Comment: scp and sftp can be used on Windows too...

Comment: Perhaps, you may need to start ssh-server on your windows first.

Comment: Windows now comes with built-in SSH server. Though I'm not sure your question really belong to this site. It's about Windows, not Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has CIFS/Samba/Windows File Sharing - which are all the same thing.

Linux can open Windows Shares using console commands, i.e. `sudo mount.cifs` or `smbclient` or using your Desktop Environment file manager.

This is the easiest and most natural way of sending/receiving files from Windows.